# Custom URI routing by query string with CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-url, codeigniter-routing

I am looking to make a custom route using the CodeIgniter framework. I am trying to make the URL like so:

```
http://localhost/accounts/Auth.dll?signin
```

So far I have tried adding the following to my routes.php config file:

```
$route['accounts/Auth.dll?signin'] = "accounts/signin";
```

but as you would guess, it doesn't work. I have also tried escaping the characters like this:

```
$route['accounts/Auth\.dll\?signin'] = "accounts/signin";
```

and that doesn't work either. I've also tried including the leading and trailing slashes .. that didn't work either. Anyone know by chance what could solve my issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I highly recommend to use a SEF routing.

But if for any reason you're not eager to, you could check the **query string** inside the `Accounts` Controller, and then **invoke** the proper **method**, as follows:

**Router:**

```php
$route['accounts/Auth.dll'] = "accounts";
```

**Controller:**

```php
class Accounts extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        # Call the CI_Controller constructor
        parent::__construct();

        # Fetch the query string
        if ($method = $this->input->server('QUERY_STRING', TRUE)) {
            # Check whether the method exists
            if (method_exists($this, $method)) {
                # Invoke the method
                call_user_func(array($this, $method));
            }
        }
    }

    protected function signin()
    {
        # Your logic here
    }
}
```

This allows you to invoke the methods by query string automatically.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion of recommending SEF urls, but this is just for a small team, no one will be using a search engine to find this.

Comment: You have saved my Time! I have been trying to achieve this by Apache mod_rewrite rules.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, that its okay to use GET-params in routes.php config.
Try such way:

**routes.php**

```
$route['accounts/Auth.dll'] = "accounts/index";
```

**accounts.php**

```
public function index() {
     if ($this->input->get('signin') != false) {
          $this->signin();
     }
}

private function signin() {
    // some code
}
```

But, as for me, it's bad way.

I recommend you just use another routing:

```
/accounts/Auth.dll/signin
```

And etc.