# CodeIgniter use question mark in routes

Tags: codeigniter, routes

I'm trying to make working routes with question mark in CodeIgniter. I wan't to do smth like this:

```
$route['smth?(:any)'] = 'smth/smth/smth_fce/$1';
```

But problem is, in CodeIgniter it tooks just string before **?** and string after it it won't pass to the function. Is there any way, to make it working?

Comment: ? is using for get method so smth_fce function don't have parameter rather use  $_get

Comment: I know, but there is no way to get it as parameter and pass to function?

Comment: adding ? makes no sense, as it's a query to the actual url, the server doesn't process it to determine state(class), it's only used inside the specific class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$route['...']` gets your url and in url anything after `?` is consider as 
query string. So directly you can't achieve what you want here.. but you can check this post [Custom URI routing by query string with CodeIgniter?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21611021/2627842) which has a similar problem and solution to it.

Comment: Thank you. I hope, your link will help.